# SPM with Git-LFS The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.BinaryReaderError error 2.)

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have created a swift package manager which contains a very large file, that's why I have uploaded it in git-lfs ( Large file storage). When I add the Swift dependency in my app this error is coming up. There no information apart from this error. My swift package manager is using xcframework in the binary target. The SPM link is https://github.com/abhisheksaralaya/CCProCalls.git . Thank you in adavnce.[image]